# Python SyntaxError when creating a list using a generator

Tags: python

I'm relatively new to Python and I'm just trying to get to grips with some of the common features.

I tried to write a simple script to get all the whole number square roots of numbers between 0 and 100. This is what I came up with:

```
mylist = [n for n*n in xrange(0,101)]
```

I got a SyntaxError when I ran it, and as far as I can tell, it's not liking the "n for n*n in" bit. Am I right in deducing that this is just not possible? Is there a way to achieve this, or do I need a sqrt() function?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need `math.sqrt` for something like this.

```
mylist = [math.sqrt(n) for n in xrange(0,101)]
```

Python isn't smart enough to see `n*n = something` and deduce that `n = math.sqrt(something)`.  It's a good thing too -- Who's to say that it shouldn't be `n = -math.sqrt(something)`?

Alternatively, you could try the builtin `map`:

```
mylist = map(math.sqrt,xrange(0,101))
```

Although most prefer the list comprehensions these days.

Sometimes, these things can be re-written a little nicer into generator expressions:

```
def square_less_than(n):
    i = 0
    while True:
       if i*i < n:
          yield i
          i += 1
       else:
          break

print list(square_less_than(10))
```

Or, the equivalent 1-liner using the excellent `itertools` module in the standard library:

```
import itertools
print list(itertools.takewhile(lambda i:i*i < 10,itertools.count()))
```

Comment: I figured as much. I don't think I fully understand what's going on with list comprehension and that's where my problem came from. Mimic the C-like for(i=0; i*i<n; i++) just isn't possible at all in Python, then?

Comment: @Richard -- that loop would be the same as `for i in xrange(int(math.sqrt(n))):` I believe -- or alternatively you could turn it into a `while` loop.  The problem is that with python, the object that you're iterating over is set up at the beginning of the loop -- whereas the `C` for loop is really a lot more like a `while` statement if you really think about it.

Comment: One problem I still have is that I just want the numbers 0-10, and not a list that goes [0, 1, 1.414, ..., 10]. Any ideas?

Comment: @Richard -- I'm not exactly sure what you want here, but I've edited to hopefully give you a few more options...

Answer (score 1):

The syntax of your list comprehension is incorrect. You can write something like:

```
import math
mylist = [math.sqrt(n) for n in xrange(0, 101)]
```

Comment: Thanks. The library import is important!

Answer (score 1):

You can also  try :

```
mylist = [n*n for n in xrange(0,101)]
```